# Android Studio debugger doesn't work in C++ code

Tags: c++, android-studio, debugging, ninja, djinni

I don't have much prior experience in Android Studio. I'm trying to debug a problem in C++ code. Djinni and ninja are used in the product. I know that the same setup with zero additional tweaks is debuggable at another machine.
But on mine, the debugger doesn't want to stop at C++ breakpoints at all. Sometimes it shows "no executable code is associated with this line" message. Other times the breakpoints are just plain red without a check mark.
Debugger log says the debugger is attached.

I don't see the "app/.cxx/Debug" folder, only the "Release" one (the other machine also has only "Release"). Build.ninja files contain release flags for cpp code. Via the search in all files in the project directory, I did not find the set of debug flags that are used in CMakeLists anywhere among the build artefacts.

It seems like I tried everything that I found on SO:

- checked for correct build variants
- checked jni debuggable true, minify enabled false, empty proguard file
- tried different debug types in Run/Debug config -> Debugger (however idk which symbol directories to add manually)
- tried debugging in an emulator as well as on a real device
- in the emulator, uninstalled the app and did cold boot
- used the same Studio version as on that other machine
- used the latest Studio version, and the newest preview
- cleared caches, cleaned, refreshed linked C++ projects
- made clean Studio reinstall with prior deep cleaning of all Gradle and Android files via Terminal
- upgraded Gradle
- use the same NDK version as in build.gradle
- added NDK dir to local.properties manually
- tried using "make module app" instead of simple "make" command

Nothing helped so far. Only once after a crash the execution stopped and showed an assembly line with a simple call stack, without details.